# Passing a PHP Varaible to google.visualization.arrayToTable

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass a PHP variable in the google.visualization to array table the code is

```
   function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Date', 'Event'],
```

now where is says 'Event' I want to dynamically replace that with a PHP variable I have tried the following but did not work..

I have Tried this but it did not work

```
     function drawChart() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Date', '<?php  echo $eventType; ?>'],

     $eventType=trim($_POST['eventType']);
     $eventType = strip_tags($eventType);
     $eventType= htmlspecialchars($eventType);
```

I want to dynamically get the $eventType based on the user's select. Please suggest how I can solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: You need to define the PHP variable before you use it, else this should work. Just switch around your Javascript function and `$eventType=trim...`

Comment: Thanks so much Danmoreng it worked!!!!